# Can't reference type in separate project

Tags: xcode, swift, linker

I have a class in a project called Infrastructure.

```
public class MyClass {

   public init() {

   }

}
```

The file that this class is defined in is in the project's list of compiled sources and the target compiles successfully.

I've imported the project name into another project's source file and referenced the class.

```
let s = MyClass()
```

I've added the Infrastructure project target to the `Link Binary With Libraries` list.

XCode has no problem recognising MyClass - it adds code completion for it.

However the compiler says,

> Use of unresolved identifier 'MyClass'

What is especially strange is that if I remove the initialiser from MyClass then the compiler does see the class but says,

> 'MyClass' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible
>   initializers

What is wrong with the solution?

I have tried cleaning the projects and deleting all of the output files.

The problem seems to be in the project doing the targeting. I'm able to reference MyClass from a different new project.

Comment: Does the file name and class name match?

Comment: It does now. No difference to the outcome though.

Comment: Defaults to internal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created new projects, proved it was possible, deleted projects, deleted the generated files and eventually it compiled.

I also changed a couple of options in the project that couldn't reference the type in order to mirror the settings in one of the new projects. Although doing this had no immediate effect. lolz.